# Why doesn't JSON.stringify include array in output JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

If I open this in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing stringify</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var obj = {};
            var arr = [];
            arr.push(1,2);
            alert(arr); // 1,2
            Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
                value:arr
            });
            alert(obj.name); // 1,2
            alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); // {}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

it will output what I've written in the comments. I don't understand why `arr` isn't included in the output JSON-string. Do I need to define some other properties on the descriptor object in `defineProperty()`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you made is non enumerable. Set `enumerable: true` in the descriptor and it'll work.

```js
var obj = {};
var arr = [];
arr.push(1, 2);
console.log(arr); // 1,2
Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
  value: arr,
  enumerable: true,
});
console.log(obj.name); // 1,2
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // {}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does the property need to be enumerable?

Comment: @Sandi: Basically because the `stringify` method needs to enumerate the properties in order to find them and add them to the JSON result. I imagine they must have made this design decision in order to be able to easily exclude properties.